# Is it possible to to tell intellisense not to scan some includes?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, intellisense

I use Visual C++ on windows xp, and I use bullet physics and Ogre3D (the latter use boost), and it seems intellisense eats all my RAM (windows XP limit is 3GB).

I'd like to tell intellisense to not scan some specific includes or directories, like boost's or bullet's, and keep Ogre's. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can, however there is a way to turn it on and off completely, have a look here

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2007/11/19/controlling-intellisense-through-macros.aspx